# Listing all transactions by a customer ID via Square API

Tags: square, square-connect

What is the best way to list all transactions per customer_id? I can't find an endpoint for this.

I've tested with `https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/{{location_id}}/transactions/customer/{{customer_id}}` 
but this clearly doesn't work. I could always look through all transactions for this particular location, but if there are hundreds/thousands of transactions, bringing all those in makes no sense, and then filter thought those to get `customer_id` specific transactions.

TIA Jaana

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "this clearly doesn't work?" It helps everyone when you can provide a more detailed explanation of "what went wrong" -- More info on finding and detailing issues: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find an endpoint for this because there is not one. You should list all transactions and then iterate through each one to find all the transactions for each `customer_id` you are interested in.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's what I thought, but I figured I better ask if I could be missing something. Do you know if an endpoint for this is planned? I can see this being very helpful if you have thousands of transactions for a location, where part are through web app, part through dashboard, and you wish to show customer specific transactions in their custom 3rd party dashboard.